# How to use printf to print long in ARM-Assembly

Tags: assembly, qemu

How do I use `printf` function to print the value of multiple `.long` in `ARM-Assembly`?

```
.global main
.extern printf
.func main

main:
    .long 15
    .long 17 
    bx lr
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply try it?

```
void fun ( long a, long b)
{
    printf("%ld %ld\n",a,b);
}
```

compiler output (edited)

```
.LC0:
    .ascii  "%ld %ld\012\000"
fun:
    mov r3, r0
    push    {r4, lr}
    mov r2, r1
    ldr r0, .L4
    mov r1, r3
    bl  printf
    pop {r4, lr}
    bx  lr
.L4:
    .word   .LC0
```

compiler output (disassembled)

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e1a03000    mov r3, r0
   4:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   8:   e1a02001    mov r2, r1
   c:   e59f000c    ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; 20 <fun+0x20>
  10:   e1a01003    mov r1, r3
  14:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <printf>
  18:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  20:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

Disassembly of section .rodata.str1.4:

00000000 <.rodata.str1.4>:
   0:   20646c25    rsbcs   r6, r4, r5, lsr #24
   4:   0a646c25    beq 191b0a0 <fun+0x191b0a0>
    ...
```

Comment: iam trying to do it the same way I did any help ?

Comment: what part dont you understand you load the operands into registers and call the function, which register holds which the compiler shows you.

Comment: @I would like to print .long for instance .long 5 then how do I print it in nxt coding thanks

Comment: see the example above where .L4 is read into a register.  no different.  or you could just try it in C and see what the compiler produces to figure out the syntax.